# python nested list value change not working

Tags: python, list, replace, nested

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
     temps = [[0]*9]*3   
# temp = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

when tries

```
temps[0][0] = 4
```

gives this output

```
[[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

tries to change the value of temp[0][0]
it changes all temp[0][0] temp[0][1] temp[0][2]
value

Comment: How did you initialize the `temp` list? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

Christian is right. `[t] * 3` is equivalent to `[t, t, t]`

You can solve it by doing this:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
     temps = [[0]*9 for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: you don't need the forloop, this just initializes temps len(arr) number of times.

Comment: @ChristianSloper you're right but I assume this is only part of the code, considering the `range(len(arr))`.